# suggest me when will the following warning occurs during compilation

Tags: cc

**temp**....is used wrong in call to sprintf or snprintf.

If copying takes place bteween objects that overlap as a result of a call to sprintf() or snprintf(), results are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't provoke a warning from gcc, even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main (void) {
    char xx[1000] = "hello";
    sprintf (xx, "xyzzy plugh %s", xx);
    printf ("%s\n", xx);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the reason why this is considered a bad idea can be seen from the output. Rather than getting:

```
xyzzy plugh hello
```

as a normal person may expect, you actually get:

```
xyzzy plugh xyzzy plugh
```

but, as with all undefined behaviour, your mileage may vary.

The definitive reference is the C99 standard, section `7.19.6.6 The sprintf function`, which states:

> The sprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output is written into an array (specified by the argument s) rather than to a stream. A null character is written at the end of the characters written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

The C++ standard (well, actually the C++0x *draft,* but it's surely due any day now, hopefully - c'mon guys, get it *out* there) references this since it incorporates parts of the C standard as deprecated functionality.